# Regex with ucwords within paren

Tags: php, regex

I have some data that I'm looping through and I'm using the below line to transform all caps into mixed caps appropriately:

```
$str = ucwords(strtolower(trim($str)));
```

Which is great except that it doesn't work so great within parentheses.  So I'm trying to run the below line afterwards to fix that problem, but it's not having any impact.  I'm seeing zero change.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\((.+)\)/e', "ucwords('$0')", $str);
```

It should turn:

```
Some Product (with Caps In Paren)
```

Into:

```
Some Product (With Caps In Paren)
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "doesn't work great within parentheses", you mean that it can't get words within parentheses, you can use the optional modifier:

```
$str = ucwords(strtolower("My string (with Caps in parens)"), '( ');
```

This will make it consider every space and parentheses as the start of a new word, and capitalize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`preg_replace_callback`**](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) instead, using `/e` modifier is frowned upon (and it's deprecated since PHP 5.5):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))/', function($matches) {
    return ucwords(strtolower(trim($matches[0])));
}, $str);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/131846). Note that I've changed the pattern as well. It now uses lookaround assertions instead of capturing groups.

Comment: I tried the pattern, but it removed everything in the parentheses and gave me two sets of parentheses which is obviously not what I wanted.

Comment: Of course, but as you see in the demo, it works. Are you sure you copied the code as is? Could you share the sample string and the output?

Comment: Not only do I feel Yaakov's solution is the cleaner way, I believe it would be more efficient to use `~\(\K[^)]+(?=\))~`.  This way the regex engine only has to look for `(` characters then release it with `\K` then start matching versus your pattern which will step through every non-`)` character then lookbehind each time to see if the previous character was a `(` then start matching when true.

Answer (score 0):

If [mbstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension is available, use [mb_convert_case](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) which converts as desired.

```
$str = mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "ASCII");
```

*converts to*:

```
Some Product (With Caps In Paren)
```

Specify [encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) if needed.

Comment: `mb_` functions are known for being rather slow.  Unless a situation cannot be appropriately solved without it, `mb_` functions should be avoided.  Otherwise a good answer that will certainly be helpful for multibyte scenarios.